# Async REST calls in scala

Tags: scala, rest, http, asynchronous

I'm using the scalaj library, which is currently synchronous, to make REST calls to the SAME endpoint repeatedly in a while loop (while updating parameters for the next call **using data I get from the previous call**, like an offset each time to get different batches of data each time). Each call currently takes about 6-7 seconds to return.

Is it possible to speed up this process using an async technique with or without scalaj? I'd just like a constant stream of data since I'm using Spark Streaming. But since I need data from the previous call for my next call, how do I make it work?

Additional details:
The aforementioned while loop is in a thread which extends Runnable, 
and the thread is submitted via Executors.newFixedThreadPool()

Comment: 6-7 seconds for an http call is quite long. What's taking up time ? The endpoint is slow ? Or is it your code ?

If it's the endpoint, you're pretty much screwed tbh, if it's your code, it's time to profile ^^

Comment: Oh no, I'm calling an endpoint which returns json objects based on a specified limit. I can modify this limit, and the time taken is proportional to # of objects returned. But even so, is there any way to do it async so it's faster?

Comment: Asynchronous does not make anything faster, it is just ... well ... asynchronous, so that while a long running task is in progress, you can do something else. But if what you need to do all depends on the result of the task, there is no point in parallelizing, because you'll have to wait for the task to complete anyway.

Comment: Is there no way to somehow queue these calls in some promise/future or something, and then execute them in a way that is quicker than normal? I'm ok with a longer initial delay at the beginning than having intermittent delays between each call.

Comment: If you are ok with initial delay, just toss batching, and get all data in one go ...

Answer (score 1):

Asynchronous does not make anything faster, it is just ... well ... asynchronous, so that while a long running task is in progress, you can do something else. But if what you need to do all depends on the result of the task, there is no point in parallelizing, because you'll have to wait for the task to complete anyway.

If your processing of the results takes some considerable time, you could do *that* in parallel with getting next batch with something like this:

```
def processBatch(batch: Batch): Future[Unit] {
  val nextBatch = Future(getNextBatch(batch))
  // do processing of the current batch
  nextBatch.flatMap { 
    case NoMoreResults => Future.successful(())
    case newBatch => processBatch(newBatch)
  }
}
```